# Do the Illusionist's Bracers allow you to concentrate on two cantrips?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, spellcasting, cantrips

[Illusionist's Bracers (GGR p178)](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/illusionists-bracers) Says:

> whenever you cast a cantrip, you can use a bonus action on the same turn to cast that cantrip a second time.

However some spells like [Create bonfire](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/create-bonfire) require concentration.
Under [spell duration](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Duration), the players handbook says:

> You lose Concentration on a spell if you cast another spell that requires Concentration. You can’t concentrate on two Spells at once.

Do the bracers allow you to concentrate on two cantrips at once?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### Nope. Things do only what they say.

Illusionist's Bracers says:

> whenever you cast a cantrip, you can use a bonus action on the same turn to cast that cantrip a second time.

It does **not** say that it makes any exception to the normal concentration rules and allow you to concentrated on more than one cantrip at a time, so you can't as per page 203 of the PHB:

> You lose Concentration on a spell if you cast another spell that requires Concentration. You can’t concentrate on two Spells at once.